# Spring MVC Validation shows multiple error messages

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I was having some problem when trying to perform validation in Spring MVC. Here is my validator class:

```
@Component
public class LossOfCardValidator implements Validator {
public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return SingleReplacementForm.class.equals(clazz);
}

public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
    SingleReplacementForm p = (SingleReplacementForm) obj;

    // check empty
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "contactNumber", "NotNull.contactNumber");
    
    // check integer
    if (!p.getContactNumber().matches("[0-9]+")) {
        e.rejectValue("contactNumber", "Format.contactNumber");
    }
}
```

In my Controller, I am calling it using this:

```
LossOfCardValidator validator = new LossOfCardValidator ();
validator.validate(singleReplacementForm, bindingResult);
```

It did performed the validation. However, in the event whereby I do not enter anything for contact number field, the two error messages will be shown. Is there anyway to modify it such that, first it will check if the field is empty, if not then proceed to check the format so that every time, there will only be one error message shown?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than doing it this way It would be much easier and clean to use validator annotation assuming you are taking a request. `@NotNull(message="")` or `@NotBlank(message="")`. You can use `@Pattern` for regex. Make your request class extend a  validator and then call it before performing

Comment: @Silverfang But then for this approach is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getFieldErrorCount](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#getFieldErrorCount-java.lang.String-) method on the `Error error` object to check whether there is already an error on the `contactNumber` field. Like this:

```
// check integer
if (e.getFieldErrorCount("contactNumber") <= 0 && !p.getContactNumber().matches("[0-9]+")) {
    e.rejectValue("contactNumber", "Format.contactNumber");
}
```

This is the easiest fix with the smallest change set. You should definitely look at `@NotNull` and `@Pattern` annotation validations.